# Intersection of decreasing sequence of non empty closed sets

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let X is Banach space. Suppose $B_n$ are decreasing sequence of non empty closed balls. Prove their intersection is non-empty.

I have some idea. Idea is pick $x_n \in B_n\backslash B_{n-1}$ in such way that $x_n$ is Cauchy sequence. Then $x_n$ will be Cauchy in each ball and each ball is closed so complete hence Cauchy sequence must converge in each ball and limit point is in each ball so it is non-empty.

Main think I don't know how to construct sequence so that it Cauchy.

Anyhelp Please!!!

Comment: Compare [An empty intersection of decreasing sequence of closed sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116852/an-empty-intersection-of-decreasing-sequence-of-closed-sets).

Comment: @MartinR A Banach space unequal to $\{0\}$ is never compact...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Yes, I meant a sequence of compact sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False, even in the reals. Try $B_n = [n, \infty)$ there.

It is true if $\operatorname{diam}(B_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$, but then this is just Cantor's intersection theorem, which holds in all complete metric spaces (not just Banach spaces).

In the latter case, just picking $x_n \in B_n$ already guarantees Cauchyness of $(x_n)_n$, and then the limit has to be proved to be in the intersection.

It seems to be true for closed balls, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22472) , and might be the intended interpretation.

Comment: it does not say diam$(B_n)$ goes to zero but it does say $B_1$ contains $B_2$ contains $B_3$ and so on.

Comment: @Toeplitz that is not enough, as my first example shows.

Comment: @Henno.what if all $B_n$ are closed ball?

Comment: @Toeplitz see edit