# Irreducible closed subset

Tags: general-topology

The *dimension* of a topological space $X$ is defined as the supremum of all integers $n\ge0$ for which there is a strictly increasing chain of $n+1$ irreducible closed subsets of $X$. Thus is the dimension of the empty topological space $-\infty$? Is the dimension $>-\infty$ for all nonempty topological spaces?

Comment: Why would the dimension of the empty set not be $-1$ by your definition?

Comment: @Matt: Because I consider it to be the supremum of a set of extended real numbers, and so the supremum of the empty set is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and yes. For your first question, since there's no such $n \ge 1$, we have $\sup \emptyset = -\infty$. So you're right. For your second question, it suffices to show that any nonempty space $X$ has at least one irreducible closed subset, so that $\dim X = \sup \{0, \dots\} \ge 0$

Since $X$ is nonempty, we can pick some $x \in X$. By [lemma 8.3 (1)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/topology.pdf#nameddest=004U), the closure of any irreducible subset is irreducible. Since $\{x\}$ is irreducible, $\overline{\{x\}}$ is an irreducible closed subset of $X$. So we're done.

**Note:** I refer to definition [8.1 (1)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/topology.pdf#nameddest=004U) for the definition of irreducible subset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @sai You can accept it if you want to.

Comment: Is this argument plausible? There is a minimal nonempty closed subset of $X$ by Zorn's lemma, and then this must necessarily be irreducible.

Comment: @sai I suppose you mean to partially order all nonempty closed subsets of $X$ by reversed inclusion $\supseteq$ and then apply Zorn's lemma. I think you would run into problem in showing any nonempty chain has an upper bound since [the intersection of a chain of nonempty closed sets can be empty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116852/an-empty-intersection-of-decreasing-sequence-of-closed-sets).

Comment: Okay, I accepted this answer. Thank you.